# My Angular app is not recognized by VSCode on runtime

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm trying a new Angular app. I've installed Node.js 15.0 to match with the last version of CLI everything is good at this point but when I want to run it in VSCode I got this error:

> Code language not supported or defined.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file extension matches the language mode you are using. If you are writing Angular code, the primary file extension would be ".ts".

Ensure that you've installed the [Angular Language Service](https://angular.io/guide/language-service) for [VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template).

If the issue persists, try restarting or reinstalling VSCode.